# Elastic Beanstalk environment configuration gets reset after a deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

1. I am using Elastic Beanstalk.
2. I add environment variables

[image]

3. I then click "Apply Changes"

[image]

4. Which then triggers the environment to update

[image]

Only once the update completes, the environment properties disappear

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: If you manually added your env variables, that's why they get rest. They have to be set in your deployment package.